# XML Schema (Attributes) and (Multiple Elements)

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

In An XML Schema. Say I already have a root element and this is a child element

```
<car type="firebird">1970 Red Firebird</car>
```

In an XML Schema how do I declare that attribute?

Also if I have more than one element and declare "minOccours" do I need to declare "maxOccours" also? I'm using this link as an example.
[XML Schema: how to have multiple identical elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799050/xml-schema-how-to-have-multiple-identical-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a "complex type with simple content"

```
<xs:complexType name="car">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  <xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

(Not tested, and not necessarily right - the syntax isn't exactly memorable).