# XML Schema Multiple Elements and Attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have this code:

```
<root>
        <skill id="1">C++</skill>
        <skill id="2">C#</skill>
        <skill id="3">Java</skill>
        <skill id="4">PHP</skill>
        <skill id="5">MYSQL</skill>
        <skill id="6">HTML</skill>
        <skill id="7">CSS</skill>
        <skill id="8">JavaScript</skill>
        <skill id="9">XML</skill>
</root>
```

I'm trying to create a schema to this and I'm not quite sure how to declare multiple elements with same name and it's attributes. [XML Schema: how to have multiple identical elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799050/xml-schema-how-to-have-multiple-identical-elements) but was unsure exactly what was going on. Do I need maxOccurs when I put a minOccurs? And in the link above I don't understand the attribute part in the schema could somebody help / elaborate please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following declares the `root` element, which can only occur once and must be specified, and a sequence of `skill` elements with an `id` attribute of type [`xs:IDREF`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#IDREF).

[`xs:attribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#cAttribute_Declarations) declares an attribute for the element. The `name` attribute specifies the attribute name.  The `type` attribute specifies the data type.

```
<xs:element name="root" minOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="skill" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:IDREF"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

> Do I need maxOccurs when I put a minOccurs?

No, you don't need to have `maxOccurs`. There is an implicit `maxOccurs="1"` if you don't specify it.

Comment: Wow great explanation. If said element has a name attribute instead of ID would it be type="xs:string"?